# Tables as Header and footer

Tags: tables, header-footer, fancyhdr, backgrounds

I've been struggling with my `.tex` for quite some time now, and decided its time to look for help.

This is the situation: all docs here (my office) need to bring, as header, a table (3 columns) which contains logo & title & page count.

Also, as footer, it must have a table (2 columns) which contains text & text.

I'm using the `book` documentstyle because I need the summary and chapter structure.

I've already tried the `\background` package, but it seens to not accept tables as content.

So, here is the question: could you point me the direction I must follow?

I wanted to include a picture, but my rep doesn't allow me....

---

Update: 05-09-2013

Trying new code now, thanks for your help!

the code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

produces the table header, but its overlapping the default header. Also, the pages in which a chapter starts, there is no header. I need headers in all pages.

Some pics:

[image: Overlapping Headers]
Overlapping Headers

[image: Blank header]

### Blank header

### -----------------------------------------------------

Initial code: 
Could you take a look at my code? its not working the way its supposed to do: its produces only a table, but not as header or footer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage[margin={2cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\setlength{\paperheight}{29.7cm} \setlength{\paperwidth}{21cm}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0,95cm}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead{
          \begin{table}[t]

          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.0cm}|}

          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \HUGE{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{Pág. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage} 

          Data: 17/05/2013

          Rev. 0}         &
          \hline

          \end{tabular}
          \end{table}
}

%I need a similar table on footer
\fancyfoot[C]{
      \begin{table}[t]

          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.0cm}|}

          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \HUGE{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{Pág. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage} 

          Data: 17/05/2013

          Rev. 0}         &
          \hline

          \end{tabular}
          \end{table}

}


\begin{document}

CONTENTS

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TX.SX! If you want, add the image to your question, and remove the leading `!`. Then a user with editing rights can add the `!` back in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a template:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   %% take the demo option out for your final document

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\includegraphics[width=12pt, height=12pt]{logo}}
\fancyhead[CE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}{cc}
                text & text
              \end{tabular}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
%% add this if you want the fancy style also on the first page of a chapter:
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Using the `fancyhdr` package, you can define headers and footers as you like. For instance, I put the logo in the header, on the left on odd pages (LO), and on the right on even pages (RE). In the center (C) of the footer I put a table as requested. The other settings are similar. Note that normally the first page of a chapter gets the page style `plain` which usually has only the page number in the footer. If you want the `fancy` style also on those pages, use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` directly after `\chapter{...}`. The template above yields:

[image: sample output]

Your code has a few problems:

- Don't set `papersize` and `paperheight` explicitly. The `a4paper` option for `book` is enough.
- The `tabular`s don't need to be wrapped into `table`s, as they are not floating objects.
- There is no `\HUGE` size, `\Huge` is the largest.
- You did not end all table rows with `\\`.

Fixing those problems leads to the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=65pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyfoot[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{10.0cm}|m{2.5cm}|}
          \hline
          \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2.5cm]{logo.png} &
          \centering
          \Huge{TITLE} &
          \centering
          \tiny{P\'ag. \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}\\
          Data: 17/05/2013\\
          Rev. 0}\tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
%% add this if you want the fancy style also on the first page of a chapter:
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

and it looks like this:

[image: sample output 2]

Note that this uses the same header and footer for odd and even pages. I think you now should be able to adapt the tables to have a right page/left page look, and setting the header with `CO` and `CE` positions accordingly.

Comment: Could you take a look at my code? its not working the way its supposed to do:

Comment: But now the table header overlaps the default header, and its not present in all pages. Pages in which a chapter starts get no headers. Let me see if I can post a pic.

Comment: This did the trick.

Comment: @erickfis You are welcome! If this fits your bill, please accept the answer, so it can go off my to-do list.