# How to add a table in footer

Tags: tables, header-footer

How can I add a table in the footer in LaTeX? I was trying to add a table that has three rows and 2 columns. In the left column, text is left-aligned, and In the right side column, text is right-aligned. The first row of the table is a merged cell with underlined text.

Here's a working example of what I am looking for. I had to add a "." for \rfoot and wondered if there's another way around. I have a different page style on a couple pages before this page, and want this page style applied to all pages on and after this page. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in, bottom=1.1in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\underline{Note: Can this be a merged cell with underlined text? Can a table be inserted here without borders?} \ Part A \ Year 1}
\rfoot{. \ Page \thepage \ Site}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/tables-as-header-and-footer), it could be helpful. And if you don't find the answer there, please edit your question and add a Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: Do you literally mean in the page *footer* (and, if that's the case, which document class and page style do you employ, and should the footer material appear on every page or just selected pages?) or in a *footnote*?

Comment: An alternative to `fancyhdr` is package `scrlayer-scrpage`. You can customize your header/footer, including multiline elements.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your
original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 3):

In the comments the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and `scrlayer-scrpage` packages have been recommended, but it's always fun to roll your own.

What you need to do is to insert your table into `\@oddfoot` and `\@even foot` -- and in turn these should both be inside your own header style that you can pass to `\pagestyle`.
Here's a fun example using the [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to produce the following page footers:

[image]

This is produced by the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[foot=4em]{geometry}% need to make the footer bigger

\makeatletter
\def\ps@mine{\ps@empty% clear all current headings and footings
\def\@oddfoot{\begin{tcolorbox}[title={This is my centered ``underlined'' text},
        colframe=blue!70!white,colback=yellow!20,colupper=red!60!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,nobeforeafter,center title,size=fbox,arc=1.5mm]
           Not sure what to put here \hfill This bit is a mystery too!\\%
           \today \hfill Page~\thepage%
       \end{tcolorbox}}
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot% odd and even page footers are the same
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As you haven't given any details, or a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it is not clear what you are looking for, but you should be able to adapt this to your needs. If you don't want something this fancy just put a [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment, of width `\textwidth`, inside the `\@oddfoot`.

---

Thank you for the suggestions. Here's a working example of what I am looking for. I had to add a "." for `\rfoot` and wondered if there's another way around. I have a different page style on a couple pages before this page, and want this page style applied to all pages on and after this page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.85in, bottom=1.1in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{black}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\fancyhf{}

\lfoot{\underline{Note: Can this be a merged cell with underlined text? Can a table be inserted here without borders?} \\  Part A \\ Year 1}

\rfoot{. \\  Page \thepage \\ Site}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one, [your next challenge](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197295/37907) ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Have tried my best but, as you said, it's not entirely clear what the OP wants...