# Two problems with my homework template: overlapping text in footer, and large fbox minipages

Tags: header-footer, templates, minipage

I begrudgingly used this template for homework through undergrad, ignoring or working around its minor issues.  I would like to finally figure out how to fix some of the problems I have with it, and in the process hopefully improve/refresh my LaTeX skills.  Other than these problems I'm very satisfied with it.

The first problem is that in the footer, the "continued on the next page" line tends to overlap with the center line in the footer: "Homework Class (Homework Class Instructor)", which typically can be relatively long.  I think it would be good to have them as separate lines in the event that the continued text is inserted.

The second problem is that the fboxes that the answers go in (as seen in `\newcommand{\problemAnswer}`) only work if the answer is less than a page long.  I think that it would be PROBABLY be easiest to just do away with the fbox, which I don't love anyway, and come up with some other kind of differentiation between question and answer.  Do you have any recommendations for an elegant way to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
% Change "article" to "report" to get rid of page number on title page
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{Tabbing}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{soul,color}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}
%units package: Pick one
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% In case you need to adjust margins:
\topmargin=-0.45in      %
\evensidemargin=0in     %
\oddsidemargin=0in      %
\textwidth=6.5in        %
\textheight=9.0in       %
\headsep=0.25in         %

% Homework Specific Information
\newcommand{\hmwkTitle}{Homework Title}
\newcommand{\hmwkDueDate}{Homework Due Date}
\newcommand{\hmwkClass}{Homework Class}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassInstructor}{Homework Class Instructor}
\newcommand{\hmwkAuthorName}{Author Name}

% Setup the header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}                                                       %
\lhead{\hmwkAuthorName}                                                 %
\rhead{\hmwkTitle}                                                      %
\lfoot{\lastxmark}                                                      %
\cfoot{\hmwkClass\ (\hmwkClassInstructor)}                             %
\rfoot{Page\ \thepage\ of\ \pageref{LastPage}}                          %
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}                                      %
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}                                      %

% This is used to trace down (pin point) problems
% in latexing a document:
%\tracingall

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Some tools
\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{\nobreak\extramarks{#1}{#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak%
                                    \nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak}%
\newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{\nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak%
                                   \nobreak\extramarks{#1}{}\nobreak}%

\newlength{\labelLength}
\newcommand{\labelAnswer}[2]
  {\settowidth{\labelLength}{#1}%
   \addtolength{\labelLength}{0.25in}%
   \changetext{}{-\labelLength}{}{}{}%
   \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{\columnwidth}#2\end{minipage}}%
   \marginpar{\fbox{#1}}%

   % We put the blank space above in order to make sure this
   % \marginpar gets correctly placed.
   \changetext{}{+\labelLength}{}{}{}}%

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\homeworkProblemName}{}%
\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}%
\newenvironment{homeworkProblem}[1][Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}]%
  {\stepcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}%
   \renewcommand{\homeworkProblemName}{#1}%
   \section{\homeworkProblemName}%
   \enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}}%
  {\exitProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}}%

\newcommand{\problemAnswer}[1]
  {\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{\columnwidth}#1\end{minipage}}}%

\newcommand{\problemLAnswer}[1]
  {\labelAnswer{\homeworkProblemName}{#1}}

\newcommand{\homeworkSectionName}{}%
\newlength{\homeworkSectionLabelLength}{}%
\newenvironment{homeworkSection}[1]%
  {% We put this space here to make sure we're not connected to the above.
   % Otherwise the changetext can do funny things to the other margin

   \renewcommand{\homeworkSectionName}{#1}%
   \settowidth{\homeworkSectionLabelLength}{\homeworkSectionName}%
   \addtolength{\homeworkSectionLabelLength}{0.25in}%
   \changetext{}{-\homeworkSectionLabelLength}{}{}{}%
   \subsection{\homeworkSectionName}%
   \enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName\ [\homeworkSectionName]}}%
  {\enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}%

   % We put the blank space above in order to make sure this margin
   % change doesn't happen too soon (otherwise \sectionAnswer's can
   % get ugly about their \marginpar placement.
   \changetext{}{+\homeworkSectionLabelLength}{}{}{}}%
\newcommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sectionAnswer}[1]
  {% We put this space here to make sure we're disconnected from the previous
   % passage

   \noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{\columnwidth}#1\end{minipage}}%
   \enterProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}\exitProblemHeader{\homeworkProblemName}%
   \marginpar{\fbox{\homeworkSectionName}}%

   % We put the blank space above in order to make sure this
   % \marginpar gets correctly placed.
   }%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Make title
\title{\vspace{2in}\textmd{\textbf{\hmwkClass:\ \hmwkTitle}}\\\normalsize\vspace{0.1in}\small{Due\ on\ \hmwkDueDate}\\\vspace{0.1in}\large{\textit{\hmwkClassInstructor}}\vspace{3in}}
\date{}
\author{\textbf{\hmwkAuthorName}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.1}
\maketitle
\newpage
% Uncomment the \tableofcontents and \newpage lines to get a Contents page
% Uncomment the \setcounter line as well if you do NOT want subsections
%       listed in Contents
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\tableofcontents
%\newpage

% When problems are long, it may be desirable to put a \newpage or a
% \clearpage before each homeworkProblem environment

\clearpage
\begin{homeworkProblem}
  Question.

  \problemAnswer
      {
        Answer.
      }
\end{homeworkProblem}

\begin{homeworkProblem}
  Question.
  \begin{homeworkSection}{Section 1 Title}
    Section 1.
    \sectionAnswer
        {
          Answer.
        }
  \end{homeworkSection}
  \begin{homeworkSection}{Section 2 Title}
    Section 2.
    \sectionAnswer
        {
          Answer.
        }
  \end{homeworkSection}
\end{homeworkProblem}

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look on the `exsheets` package, it will provide some better means, I think. (No, I am **not** the author of `exsheets` ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can get your frames to continue on the next page using the [framed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed) package and changing the definition of `\problemAnswer` to

```
\newcommand{\problemAnswer}[1]{\begin{framed}#1\end{framed}}
```

For the continuation messages you need to either shorten some of the material appearing in the footers or to put the continuation messages on a different line. One possibility for a "shorter" version is to use:

```
\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1}{#1 continues\ldots}\nobreak%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{#1 continues\ldots}\nobreak}%
\newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{#1 continues\ldots}\nobreak%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1}{}\nobreak}%
```

For your MWE this produces:

[image]

By accident I found a hack that shifts the continuation messages to the next line. I have not tried to work out what causes this but if you just add `\color{black}` in appropriate places then your footer messages look like this:

[image]

This was done using:

```
\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1}{#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{\color{black}#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak}%
\newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1 (Continued)}{\color{black}#1 continued on next page\ldots}\nobreak%
     \nobreak\extramarks{#1}{}\nobreak}%
```

This said, if I was writing something like this I'd probably use the [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package both for your framed homework boxes and for the footers. For example of what you can do in the footers this way see
[how-to-add-a-table-in-footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197288/how-to-add-a-table-in-footer/197336#197336).