# Table as Header - How to?

Tags: tables, header-footer

I am completely new to Tex and I want to include a table into a header. Since I have no clue how to do that I searched the forum and found: [Tables as Header and footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/tables-as-header-and-footer)

But I am not able to change it and I need a second row. So I came across excel2latex but combining the template I found here on stack exchange and the excel2latex lines makes a mess. :-(

This is the code excel2latex gave me:

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Tabelle1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|cccc|rrr|r|}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[2]{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Berufschule}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Name:} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Klasse:} \\
          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{10}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Instandhaltung} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Datum:} &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Blatt:} \\
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{maintenance} &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

And this is what I need (Picture):

[image: Header as table]

Anyone a few tipps for a newbe?

Comment: Thank you, especially for editing the code. It is way better now! :-)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by header? Is it a title, or a typographical header, which appears at the top of  every page of the document?

Comment: The second one. I want the table as a header for each page. It is for a worksheet for students. I am a teacher.

Comment: Please don't underline text. Sei ein Vorbild.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See, if this is what you after:

[image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[top=5cm,headheight=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|cX|X|p{2cm}|}
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
    &   \textbf{Berufschule}    &   Name    &   Klasse:         \\
    &                           &           &                   \\
    &                           &           &   \textbf{10}     \\
    \hline
    & \makecell[t]{Instandhaltung\\ maintenance}
                                &   Datum:  &   Blatt:          \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
            }

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Table as header are set by help of package `fancyheader` Table in header had not be in float environment (`table`), but directly put in it.

That table span text width I suggest to use `tabularx` table environment. First column is standard  `c` type for logo picture, next two are `X` type (defined by `tabularx` package), which automatically determine column width, the last one is standard ˙p{}`, where for width I select 2cm.

For table with vertical line the rules form package `booktabs` aren't appropriate. For two-line cell I use `makecell`, whic in the same time horizontal center cell content.

Edit:
I correct appearing of cell with two line content. Before (without option `t`) was vertical centered, now, with option `[t]` is top aligned with other cells contents.

If you like to have only page header in sans sheriff fonts, than you need to add `\sffamilly` in fancy header definition.

Comment: YES!!!! OMG! This is perfect! Thank you so much! You sir, are a genius!

Comment: @Chris, see edit of my answer (i have problems with upload it in one piece :-( ). Image and some description is added now.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to a little space between the header and the following text? If I insert some text it starts right under the line. I trued \vspace{2cm} but no luck. Also I am having trouble to insert ä,ö,ü - which are used a lot in German language. It is supposed to work with \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} but for some reason it does not work. Do you know how to fix those things, too?

Comment: page layout is determined by package `geometry`.  In answer I use default values except for header height and top margin. If selected is not adequate, you should change it. For example `\usepackage[top=6cm,headheight=3cm]{geometry}` determine top margin 6 cm and from it 3 cm is reserved for header height.  Regarding "umlauts" you should use  correct coding. I suggest add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in preamble. For german hyphenation you need add babel, for example `\usepackage[newgeman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution, based on `geometry`, `tabularx` and `titleps`:

```
\documentclass[,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\geometry{top=45mm, headheight=76pt}%
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{booktabs} % commands for table rules
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx,  lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{myheader}{%
\sethead{}{%
\sffamily\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}\color{LightSteelBlue}
\raisebox{0.87\height}[0pt]{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{~}X|X|p{25mm}|}
\toprule
\raisebox{-0.7\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{BugsBunny}} &  \textbf{Berufschule} & Name: & \makecell[tl]{Klasse:\\[3ex]\textbf{10}} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell[t]{Instandhaltung\\maintenance}}  & Datum: & Blatt: \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}}{}%
\setfoot{}{\sffamily\thepage}{}
}%

\pagestyle{myheader}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]