# Complex Table as Header

Tags: tables, header-footer, resize

I've been trying to make a proper header for my lab reports, that uses a table with 2 pictures. Thing is, each cell in the table has a different length.

Using [this online table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) I was kind of able to emulate the tables my university uses as headers.

The code I got is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                                     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\batchmode
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
\usepackage{geometry}                                                       
\geometry{left=13mm,right=13mm,top=21mm,bottom=21mm}

\usepackage{float}                                                                          
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}                                                  


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|l|l|c|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}
       {\tiny \textsc{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Universidad de Costa Rica\\ 
        Escuela de Ingeniería Eléctrica\\ Departamento de Electrónica Y 
        Telecomunicaciones\end{tabular}}}   
       & 
       {\tiny \textsc{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\hfill \adjustbox{valign=t] 
       {\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1.10cm]{images/escudo}
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=1.10cm]{images/eie}}
       \hfill Pág.\thepage \\ \end{tabular}}}  \\

        \hline

        {\tiny \textsc{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Preparado por: \\
        Author, ID\\ Author, ID\\ Author, ID \end{tabular}}  }    
        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}
        {{\tiny \textsc{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}IE|0307 Electromagnetismo
          I - I Ciclo 2018\\ Laboratorio de Electromagnetismo y 
          Radiofrecuencia|Reporte Práctica Experimental 01\\ 
         \end{tabular}}}} \\ 

        \hline

    \end{tabular}%
} 
\blindtext[25]
\end{document}
```

And with that the result I get is this:

[image: Table Obtained]

The thing is that I'm not familiar to the *facyheader* package, and I haven't been able to put that table as a header.

Also, I'm supposed to put the date beneath the page count, but I'm not able to, because of how the table is structured.

I've seen similar posts such as [Table as Header and Footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/tables-as-header-and-footer) and [Table as Header - How to?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333240/table-as-header-how-to) but none are quite the same, and I've been hard stuck with this.  I would greatly appreciate if you could help me understand this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

based on my answer to question [Table as Header - How to?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333240/table-as-header-how-to):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=5cm,headheight=2cm]{geometry}
%\geometry{left=13mm,right=13mm,top=21mm,bottom=21mm}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\batchmode
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
    \tiny
    \scshape
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|}
    \hline
Universidad de Costa Rica\newline
Escuela de Ingeniería Eléctrica\newline
Departamento de Electrónica Y\newline
Telecomunicaciones
    &   \hfill%
        \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1.10cm, valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 0pt]{images/escudo}
        \quad
        \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=1.10cm, valign=t,margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 0pt]{images/eie}
        \hfill Pág.\thepage \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}      \\[-1pt]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}C
                                  |>{\hsize=0.75\hsize}C|}
\makecell{Preparado por: \\
Author, ID\\
Author, ID\\
Author, ID}
    & \makecell{Electromagnetismo I - I Ciclo 2018\\
      Laboratorio de Electromagnetismo y Radiofrecuencia
          -- Reporte Práctica Experimental 01}                   \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
            }

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\blindtext[25]
\end{document}
```

in real document please remove `graphicx`'s option `demo`.